# Degrees of Freedom of Cross-Level Interactions Terms in LME/LMER models

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, degrees-of-freedom

I am currently working on a hierarchical linear model using a dataset with variables on two levels. Level 1 variables have roughly 90000 observations and level 2 variables 141 observations. Unfortunately, I cannot share a sample of my data because it is confidential.

When I estimate a model with cross-level interaction terms using the lme-command, the summary-command shows that they are estimated with 90319 degrees of freedom, as demonstrated by this example:

```
   Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
   Data: Data4 
   AIC      BIC    logLik
   24549.23 24605.71 -12268.62

   Random effects:
    Formula: ~1 | BU_SBU
     (Intercept)  Residual
    StdDev:   0.1150382 0.2762167

    Fixed effects: OTIF ~ COLT * cap_20 
                   Value  Std.Error    DF    t-value p-value
  (Intercept)  0.5990647 0.01940455 90319  30.872383  0.0000
  COLT        -0.0028250 0.00010048 90319 -28.115393  0.0000
  cap_20       0.0225735 0.01123800   139   2.008674  0.0465
  COLT:cap_20  0.0001599 0.00005073 90319   3.152416  0.0016
   Correlation: 
              (Intr) COLT   cap_20
  COLT        -0.083              
  cap_20      -0.857  0.060       
  COLT:cap_20  0.069 -0.861 -0.067

  Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
         Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
  -5.4213246 -0.5560970  0.1767612  0.7154896  6.6255524 

  Number of Observations: 90462
  Number of Groups: 141
```

Now my questions: *Is it valid to calculate the standard errors of interactions terms based on the degrees of freedom obtained through the number of level 1 observations?*

The reason I am asking this question is that I keep on getting highly significant interactions terms in my analysis when no or little interaction would be expected at all.

I appreciate your help!

Best,

Christian